# How many the limit characters ksoap2 receiver from webservice?

Tags: android

I call a webservice with ksoap2 in my android app.
I want get a large data. 
I had test: if data receiver (json) about 2.000.000 character, my app runs ok
 if data receiver (json) about 6.000.000 character, my app runs die (force close because OutOfMemoryError).
Do you known correct:
How many limit characters ksoap2 receiver from webservice?

Answer (score 1):

The byte limits is based on the memory liimit of your app/device, if the result is huge what you can do is store it file first before parsing it or use one of the stream parsers namely:

JsonReader - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html

or if you are using Gson then try

JsonStreamParser - http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonStreamParser.html